# "NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethodSelector" in Spring Security OAuth after upgrading from Spring 4.3 to 5.0

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Spring 4.3 to 5.0 and ran into what seems to be an issue in Spring Security OAuth. In particular a stack of nested bean creation failures of the form:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2EndpointHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethodSelector
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2EndpointHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethodSelector
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethodSelector
```

It appears that *org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector* got deprecated in late-ish Spring 4.x releases and then removed altogether in Spring 5.x.

The actual versions I'm trying to make work together are:

- Spring Framework: 5.0.6
- Spring Security: 5.0.6
- Spring Security OAuth: 2.3.3

The Spring Security OAuth version is the latest so I'm not sure where to go next. Is there just not a version of it that's compatible with Spring 5.x? If that's the case, what are my options?

Comment: Any luck fixing this issue?

Comment: No, @TerNovi. I've been diverted onto other work since making the post. But I'll be getting back to this work eventually and will post updates if I make any progress.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by spring in the javadoc of the class, from version 4.3 it is deprecated. It is recommended to use, instead of *MethodIntrospector*

```
package org.springframework.web.method;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.MethodFilter;

    /**
 * Defines the algorithm for searching handler methods exhaustively including interfaces and parent
 * classes while also dealing with parameterized methods as well as interface and class-based proxies.
 *
 * @author Rossen Stoyanchev
 * @since 3.1
 * @deprecated as of Spring 4.2.3, in favor of the generalized and refined {@link MethodIntrospector}
 */
@Deprecated
public abstract class HandlerMethodSelector {

    /**
     * Select handler methods for the given handler type.
     * <p>Callers define handler methods of interest through the {@link MethodFilter} parameter.
     * @param handlerType the handler type to search handler methods on
     * @param handlerMethodFilter a {@link MethodFilter} to help recognize handler methods of interest
     * @return the selected methods, or an empty set
     * @see MethodIntrospector#selectMethods
     */
    public static Set<Method> selectMethods(Class<?> handlerType, MethodFilter handlerMethodFilter) {
        return MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(handlerType, handlerMethodFilter);
    }

}
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethodSelector.java

As indicated in the migration guide to version 5:

> Many deprecated classes and methods removed across the codebase.

[What's New in Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security OAuth 2.3.3 is tested [up to Spring Security 5.0.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.3.3.RELEASE/pom.xml#L170). (You might try with the dependencies listed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.3.3.RELEASE/pom.xml#L170,L173) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/pom.xml#L28,L31), just to remove that noise while you are researching.)

That said, the Spring Security OAuth2 Autoconfig project [builds against Spring Boot 2.1.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth2-boot/blob/master/gradle/dependency-management.gradle), which uses Spring Security 5.1.0 and Spring Security OAuth 2.3.4, so I would not anticipate any inevitable classpath issues.

If you haven't already, it would be worth double-checking your dependency tree to see if there are any unexpected dependencies.

Or, if you can repro it with a minimal sample, you could post it - it might make the issue a little clearer.

And, lastly, the Spring Security 5.x series releases a new, fully-integrated OAuth module, which has placed the Spring Security OAuth plugin library into maintenance mode. You can track the [feature diff](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix) to see if 5.1 has the features you need to be able to drop the plugin.